# JAVA CharacterIO cannot figure out how to append

Tags: java, append, character

I have this piece of code which I cannot figure out what doesn't work. I tried all possible combinations and I am getting nowhere. The point of this code is that it should copy a text file and the content into another file, when the 3rd argument is "r". That works fine, but when I try to append the content in the file it won't work and I cannot figure it out. Here is the code below.
I seperated the part which is not working.

```
import java.io.*;

public class Copy
{   
public static void main(String[] args)
{

  if(args.length == 3)
  {
     try
     {                 
           FileReader inputFile = new FileReader(args[0]);
           FileWriter outputFile = new FileWriter(args[1]);
           int chr = inputFile.read();

           while (chr != -1)
           {
              outputFile.write(chr);
              chr = inputFile.read();
           }
           outputFile.flush();          
           if(args[2].equals("r"))
           {
              chr = inputFile.read();

              while(chr != -1)
              {
                 outputFile.write(chr);
                 chr = inputFile.read();
              }
           outputFile.flush();
           }



else if(args[2].equals("a"))
    {
       chr = inputFile.read();

       while(chr != -1)
       {
          outputFile.write(chr);
          chr = inputFile.read();
       }
       outputFile.flush();
   }


     }
     catch(IOException e)
     {
        System.out.println("Exception: " +  e.getMessage());
     }
     }
     else
     {
        System.out.println("Invalid number of args. Program will exit.");
        System.exit(0);
     }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first `while` loop, you are reading the input file and writing it to a different file completely. That is why when you try to invoke `read()` again in the `if...` loops again, it will throw an exception since the file has already been completely read. Remove the following code (the 1st while loop):

```
       int chr = inputFile.read();

       while (chr != -1)
       {
          outputFile.write(chr);
          chr = inputFile.read();
       }
       outputFile.flush();
```

and replace it with just

```
int chr;
```

---

EDIT:
In your 2nd condition (for append) use the following code:

```
else if(args[2].equals("a"))
           {
    FileReader outputFileInReadMode = new FileReader(args[1]);
    int count = 0;
    int ichr=0;
    while (ichr!=-1){ichr=outputFileInReadMode.read();count++);} //This measures the 
//current size of the output file
              chr = inputFile.read();

              while(chr != -1)
              {
                 outputFile.write(chr, count++); //Index to write to
                 chr = inputFile.read();
              }
              outputFile.flush();
           }
```

Comment: Thank you, I have done as you said but it still only copies the file and content. When I enter "a" as an argument it still does nothing...

Comment: I've made some changes to my answer, please try this.

Comment: outputFile.write(chr, count++);  -  it wont compile count++ and also, nothing really changed :(

Answer (score 0):

Ok, solution found.
All I needed to do was call the FileWriter in both if statements ("r" & "a") and now it is working as it should. Thank you Chetan Jadhav for the assistance :)